# How can I convert a bytestring array in a hex string in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have a bytestring from a socket connection:

```
>>> var
b'\xb5\x1a'
```

How can i convert this (little endian order) into a Hex string like:

```
>>> var2
0x1AB5
```

I tried:

```
>>> var.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: invalid start byte

>>> var.from_bytes(2,'little')
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'from_bytes'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) method will help.

> *int.from_bytes(bytes, byteorder, *, signed=False)* -> *int*
>
> Return the integer represented by the given array of bytes.
>
> ...
>
> If byteorder is 'little', the most
>   significant byte is at the end of the byte array.

It will convert bytes to integer:

```
In [1]: int.from_bytes(b'\xb5\x1a', 'little') # 'little' for little-endian order
Out[1]: 6837
```

Then you can use [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex)

```
In [2]: hex(int.from_bytes(b'\xb5\x1a', 'little'))
Out[2]: '0x1ab5'
```

or [`format(..., '#x')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format)

```
In [3]: format(int.from_bytes(b'\xb5\x1a', 'little'), '#x')
Out[3]: '0x1ab5'
```

to get hexadecimal representation.

Other solutions include [`base64.b16encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b16encode)

```
In [4]: import base64

In [5]: '0x' + base64.b16encode(b'\xb5\x1a'[::-1]).decode('ascii')
Out[5]: '0x1AB5'
```

and [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
In [24]: '0x' + binascii.hexlify(b'\xb5\x1a'[::-1]).decode('ascii')
Out[24]: '0x1ab5'
```

---

Some timings for `bytestr = b'\xb5\x1a'`:

```
In [32]: %timeit hex(int.from_bytes(bytestr, 'little'))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 267 ns per loop

In [33]: %timeit format(int.from_bytes(bytestr, 'little'), '#x')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 465 ns per loop

In [34]: %timeit '0x' + base64.b16encode(bytestr[::-1]).decode('ascii')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 746 ns per loop

In [35]: %timeit '0x' + binascii.hexlify(bytestr[::-1]).decode('ascii')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 545 ns per loop
```

For `bytestr = b'\xb5\x1a' * 100`:

```
In [37]: %timeit hex(int.from_bytes(bytestr, 'little'))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 992 ns per loop

In [38]: %timeit format(int.from_bytes(bytestr, 'little'), '#x')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.2 µs per loop

In [39]: %timeit '0x' + base64.b16encode(bytestr[::-1]).decode('ascii')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 µs per loop


In [40]: %timeit '0x' + binascii.hexlify(bytestr[::-1]).decode('ascii')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 983 ns per loop
```

`int.from_bytes` is (predictably) fast for small byte strings, `binascii.hexlify` is fast for longer byte strings.